# Swift 2.0 Alamofire Completion Handler Return Json

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

My goal is to create a simple function where I pass in a url and it returns me JSON. I have looked around and found little examples of where a completion handler is implemented with Alamofire.

I am also using Swifty Json to help parse it out.

How do I turn what I have here to a function where it returns my Json.

```
func request() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, API_END_POINT)
    .responseJSON {
        response in

        // swiftyJsonVar is what I would like this function to return.
        let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I edited my description: How do I turn what I have here to a function where it returns my Json.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Swift 3+** and **Alamofire 4+**

```
 // Call function
    myFunction("bodrum") { response in
      print(response["yourParameter"].stringValue)
    }

    // POST
    func myFunction(_ cityName:String, completion: @escaping (JSON) -> ()) {

      let token = "token"
      let parameters = ["city" : cityName]
      let headers = ["Authorization": "token"]
      let url = URL(string: "url")!
      let reqUrl = URLRequest(url: url)

      Alamofire.request(reqUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
          switch response.result {
          case .Success:
            let jsonData = JSON(data: response.data!)
            completion(jsonData)
          case .Failure(let error):
            MExceptionManager.handleNetworkErrors(error)
            completion(JSON(data: NSData()))
          }
      }
    }
```

**Swift 2** and **Alamofire 3+**

```
// POST
func myFunction(cityName:String, completion : (JSON) -> ()) {
  Alamofire.request(.POST, "url", parameters: ["city" : cityName], encoding: ParameterEncoding.JSON, headers: ["Authorization": "token"])
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { response in
      switch response.result {
      case .Success:
        let jsonData = JSON(data: response.data!)
        completion(jsonData)
      case .Failure(let error):
        MExceptionManager.handleNetworkErrors(error)
        completion(JSON(data: NSData()))
      }
  }
}

// GET
func myFunction(cityName:String, completion : (JSON) -> ()) {
  Alamofire.request(.GET, "url", parameters: ["param1" : cityName], headers: ["Authorization": "token"])
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { response in
      switch response.result {
      case .Success:
        let jsonData = JSON(data: response.data!)
        completion(jsonData)
      case .Failure(let error):
        MExceptionManager.handleNetworkErrors(error)
        completion(JSON(data: NSData()))
      }
  }
}

// Call function
myFunction("bodrum") { response in
  print(response["yourParameter"].stringValue)
}
```

Comment: This looks great! But can you show me how to call this correctly? I don't think its as simple as: var json = myFunction("myParam")

Comment: Awesome! It works like a charm, just had to play with the Failure handling b.c. of getting a unresolved identifier but thats no biggy, thank you very much :)

Comment: @fatihyildizhan could you please update your code for Alamofire 4.0 and Swift 3 ?